# Django: Uploading a CSV file to AWS S3

Tags: python, django, csv, boto3

We have a Django application that needs to create a csv file on user demand and upload it to AWS S3. We have a function that creates an `HttpResponse` object `response` with `content_type="text/csv"` We have tried a number of things:

1. `boto3`:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.put_object(Body=response.content, Bucket="my-bucket", Key="file_path_and_name.csv")
```

This worked in my local machine, but when deployed to Google App Environment, we got an error that said boto3 could not find credentials. The AWS credentials are in our app settings file. (How would it work on my local machine if we didn't?)

2. `django-storages`: We have successfully used storages to allow users to download files from this same s3 bucket, within the same app (both locally and deployed). So I thought I would give it a try:

```
storage = S3Boto3Storage()
storage.save("file_path_and_name.csv", response.content)
```

This produced the error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`
This is because the `save` method in `S3Boto3Storage` calls `content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)`
So... Does that mean `S3Boto3Storage` cannot take a bytestring input file, like `boto3` does? (I thought the `S3Boto3Storage` backend was built right on top of `boto3`?)
I tried `io.StringIO(response.content.decode("utf-8"))` but I got another error that said the string needed to be encoded before it was hashed. At that point, I figured that had to be a better, more direct way of doing it.

Is there a way to fix either of these approaches?

The third option I am contemplating is to modify the function that creates the HttpResponse object and make it write the csv directly into s3 using an `S3Boto3StorageFile` file object and the same csv writer. But the documentation on such a thing is rather lacking (at least for my level of expertise). I would welcome some advice in that direction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to get it to work: Provide the credentials directly in the `boto3.client` call:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            aws_access_key_id=config("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
            aws_secret_access_key=config("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
        )
```

Note: I am using the `decouple` package to keep my credentials safe. That's what the `config("...")` call is about.

The reason my local machine did not need the specific credentials is that I had set up AWS cli, which means my credentials were stored in a local file at `~/.aws/credentials` and `boto3` could find them there